Serial limits on postgres
I have a question about the limits of the smallserial type on postgres, as I read in the official docs, the limits of an smallinteger comes from -32768 to 32767 using a storage of 2 bytes.
But the limits of the smallserial comes from 1 to 32767 using the same 2 bytes.
My question is, if both are using the same 2 bytes, and smallserial uses only positive numbers, why it has the same upper limit than smallinteger?
Postgres docs about numbers
So, for me the most logic way of doing this is adding more positive limit to the serial type.
I'm missing something but I don't know what it is.
Can you help me? Thank you very much!

A serial is not a real data type: it's an alias for (in this case) a small integer and a default call to a sequence that starts with the number 1. Just create your own and the problem is solved.


FYI, there is nothing stopping you from using Alter Sequence to reset the minvalue to -32768. 2) If you want only positive numbers and more then what smallserial(smallint) gives you then use serial(integer) or bigserial(bigint).

